# Difference between two lists in Java

Tags: java, list, data-structures

I started learning data structures and algorithms with Java.

I started with list and the first concept which I learnt is difference between array and list.

Now in list I learn how to insert and element in to list and displaying on the screen. I got two pieces of code. The first one I understood very well; where the second one is confusing.

My confusion is what is the *Node* here? In the beginning we declare `Node head;`. So basically what is *Node* here?

Is it predefined datatype or something? Also, how does the second program flow? How is the second program different from the first? And what is the difference?

Also I understood that we are using util here, but still I want to know because how people use it in the industry.

The first method:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestCollection7 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        LinkedList<String> al = new LinkedList<String>();
        al.add("Ravi");
        al.add("Vijay");
        al.add("Ravi");
        al.add("Ajay");

        Iterator<String> itr = al.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Second method:

```
package javaapplication3;

public class LIstTEst {
    Node head;

    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d) {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    public void PrintList() {
        Node n = head;
        while(n != null){
            System.out.print(n.data+" ");
            n = n.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LIstTEst llist = new LIstTEst();
        llist.head = new Node(1);
        Node second = new Node(2);
        Node third = new Node(7);

        llist.head.next = second;
        second.next = third; = third;

        llist.PrintList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind that your second example has a flaw: first, you set `head.next` to `second` which would be ok. But right after, you set it to "third" which is wrong. You should set `second.next` to `third`. As is, you lose `second` node from the list. Actually the list implementation should have an `add` method that creates a new Node, sets its value and sets the tail's `next` reference to the new node. To make it clear: Your list ends up in "head-> third" but should be "head->second->third".

Comment: @Fildor You are correct I change my code here in my local debugger.

Comment: @Fildor SO basically you are suggesting I should use `add` method instead of Node and all.

Comment: No, you still need the Node class. But your client shouldn't deal with it directly. Your list implementation should provide an API that abstracts from dealing with the node references. All a user should use are methods like `void add(int newValue)` for example. Look at the API of LinkedList. It uses Nodes, too but as the client, you are not aware of that.

Comment: Does it even compile? `second.next = third; = third;` looks suspicious (changed in [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43178856/3)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Node` is a class nested inside `LIstTEst`.

You have its definition:

```
static class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

It represents a link in a linked list. It contains a numeric value (`data`) and a reference to the next `Node` in the list.

```
Node head;
```

is a member of the `LIstTEst` which refers to the first link in the list.

Note that the posted implementation of `LIstTEst` is lacking. It should use an `add` method instead of the `main` creating `Node`s and directly manipulating the links.

Comment: Actually, in the example posted, there is a flaw. It loses `second` node.

Comment: @Eran Excellent explanation. One quick question which one should I follow first or second to understand list. And later I may get tough days in terms of problem in list.

Comment: @shankysingh Depends on what you want to learn. You want to learn Java List interface? Then play around with List implementations. You want to learn about the datastructure "List" as a concept? Use own implementations.

Comment: @Fildor When you say use own explanation, What do you refering for. Any example.

Comment: "Own implementation" = your second example. It is a singly linked list. You could make others that implement doubly linked list ( Nodes have refs to next and previous Nodes) or ArrayList (Nodes are accessible by index using arrays "under the hood").

Comment: @shankysingh It depends on your purpose. In general should definitely use existing classes (such as java.util.LinkedList) instead of re-inventing the wheel. You should only care about the second implementation if you wish to learn how to implement a LinkedList yourself (of course you'll need a better implementation).

Comment: Thanks @Eran I will focus on second implementaion to understand data structure well.

Comment: @shankysingh "Then play around with List implementations." - oh that was confusing, sorry. I meant the implementations in the java library like LinkedList, ArrayList, ...

Comment: Sure @Fildor Also will appreciate you give me some links. :)

Comment: There you go: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Answer (score 2):

That

```
public class LIstTEst
```

is nothing else but the **first** step towards self-implementing a **list**. Whereas your first piece of source code makes use of the linked list implementation that comes as part of the "standard" Java collection classes.

A "linked list" (in generic terms) is nothing else but, well, a list of **connected** thingies (of the same type). Those "thingies" are expressed using that internal `Node` class.

Thus, the real answer is: avoid mixing up concepts and implementation. In order to understand how Java is dealing with "linked lists"; you should first step back and understand the concept "linked list" itself. For example, by reading its [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) entry:

> In computer science, a linked list is a linear collection of data elements, called nodes, each pointing to the next node by means of a pointer. It is a data structure consisting of a group of nodes which together represent a sequence. Under the simplest form, each node is composed of data and a reference (in other words, a link) to the next node in the sequence. This structure allows for efficient insertion or removal of elements from any position in the sequence during iteration. More complex variants add additional links, allowing efficient insertion or removal from arbitrary element references.

In other words: programming languages are about *implementing* common algorithms and data structures for that given language. Therefore it is very much advised to start your research by learning about those common concepts.

Beyond that: the reason why you might find the second example confusing:

- probably you have not learned about [inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) yet
- the example is incomplete; important methods to add or remove list elements are still missing!

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes I will look on inner classes.

Comment: You are very welcome. But for the record: those are very basic things. One element of learning is, to well, look out for sources of information yourself. Asking other people to explain stuff works; yes; but **finding** the answers yourself is A) where the fun and B) the long-term "learning experience" really is.

Answer (score 0):

#### First example

LinkedList is an implementation of a linked-list data structure in Java.

#### Second example

It is manually written implementation of the same data structure. *Node* is you class, which describes one cell in this linked list.

Both implementations are not the same. Java's implementation provides a bunch of convenient methods to work with list, while yours do not. You can start with an implementation of `add` method.

```
// Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
public void add(int data) {

    // Create Node only in case of first element
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node(data);
    }

    Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head;

    // Check if there is first element
    if (current != null) {

        // Starting at the head node, iterate to the end of the list and then add element after last node
        while (current.getNext() != null) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        // The last node's "next" reference set to our new node
        current.setNext(temp);
    }
}
```

#### What is a linked list?

Long story short: a linked list is a chain of cells. Each cell knows about the next one. The last cell knows that there is no next cell. A linked-list class (which manipulates those cells (nodes)) contains reference for the first node.

[image]

Look at this interactive demo: https://visualgo.net/list

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LIstTEst {
    Node head; // ==> Declaring a Class level variable.

    static class Node { // Create a static class
        int data; // Integer data type variable.
        Node next; // Class refrernce.

        Node(int d) { // Create a constructor.
            data = d; // Holding the current value.
            next = null;
        }
    }

    public void PrintList() {
        Node n = head;
        while (n != null) {
            System.out.print(n.data + " ");
            n = n.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LIstTEst llist = new LIstTEst(); // Creating a object of the mentioned
                                         // class.

        llist.head = new Node(1);        // Creating the Node class object by Class
                                         // level refrence.

        Node second = new Node(2);       // As this is static class, inside one class,
                                         // so we created directly to object of Node
                                         // class by passing the parameter to the
                                         // constructor.
        Node third = new Node(7);

        llist.head.next = second; // Just transfering the current reference to
                                  // next level reference before that
                                  // constructor is making null for each
                                  // executions.
        llist.head.next = third;

        llist.PrintList(); // Finally for printing purpose it is calling.
    }
}
```